# spark iterate consecutive elements in list to rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a spark rdd with a column like

List(1, 3, 4, 8)

List(2, 3)

List(1, 5, 6)

I would like to get a new rdd with consecutive elements in each list to rows, like

(1, 3)

(3, 4)

(4, 8)

(2, 3)

(1, 5)

(5, 6)

How can I achieve this with scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

1. using a complementary (plain Scala) function with signature `List[Int] => List[(Int, Int)]` to achieve the desired result for the single list

   and
2. passing this function to your RDD's `flatMap` method.

This complementary function may look like this:

```scala
def makeTuples(l: List[Int], 
               acc: List[(Int, Int)] = List.empty): List[(Int, Int)] = 
  l match {
    case Nil | _ :: Nil => acc.reverse
    case a :: b :: rest => makeTuples(b :: rest, (a, b) :: acc)
  }
```